# Количество целей

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть предложение: "Эта вода используется в хозяйственных целях". Понятно, что цель эта не одна: и огород полить, и радиатор залить. Но допустим, что вода предназначена только для одной конкретной цели. Можно ли в этом случае сказать "используется для хозяйственной цели"? Ведь не мы не говорим "вода используется с целями полива огорода", а скажем "используется с целью полива огорода".
Так сколько же целей должно быть?

Answer (score 3):

"В целях" – так принято говорить. Устойчивое сочетание. Канцеляризм. Хотите говорить "для цели" – ну, говорите. Но лучше, если цель одна, так и говорить: для полива огорода.

И еще: все зависит от того, что это за текст. Официальная бумага? Тогда лучше "в целях". Канцеляризм оправдан.

Comment: Правильно "в целях чего" и "с целью что сделать", то есть "в целях полива огорода", как это ни парадоксально, и "с целью полить огород".

Answer (score 1):

Существуют выражения "в промышленных целях, в хозяйственных целях", имеющие значение "в различных областях хозяйства и промышленности". Для выражения общего понятия можно сказать, что вода применяется в промышленности или хозяйстве.

Словосочетание "для промышленной или хозяйственной цели" будет таким грамматическим плеоназмом, то есть выражением, не добавляющим нового смысла, но имеющим более сложную структуру.